# Define preprocessor value when value not defined

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Sometimes I see a `define` preprocessor but not value assigned to it.  For example:

```
#define VAR
```

What is assigned to `VAR` when no value is specified?

I am also reading a text and I see:

```
#ifndef ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H
#define ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H

/* Error diagnostic routines */

void errMsg(const char *format, ...);

#ifdef __GNUC__

    /* This macro stops 'gcc -Wall' complaining that "control reaches
       end of non-void function" if we use the following functions to
       terminate main() or some other non-void function. */

#define NORETURN __attribute__ ((__noreturn__))
#else
#define NORETURN
#endif
```

Is  `ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H` a header file? Or is that just a constant defined by `define` preprocessor?

Comment: The `#define VAR` has an empty string as its replacement value.  You can test whether it is set.  If it appears in a context other than `defined` (or `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`), then it gets replaced with nothing.  The `NORETURN` macro is an example of where the replacement text is nothing when the compiler is not GCC (or does not claim to be GCC -- beware `clang`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just 'defined' so you can do checks like `#ifdef ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H`

So if you have

```
 #define ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H
```

You can later do:

```
#ifdef ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H
 //do something
#endif
```

and the code inside the #ifdef will be compiled.

`ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H` is not a header file.  It is just a `#define` for the preprocessor to use.

What you have in your example:

```
#ifndef ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H
#define ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H
```

is often put at the top of a .h file to make sure it is only included once so you don't get multiple defines.

Comment: Thanks @edtheprogrammerguy... Are you sure about your answer?  Is xd6_ wrong?

Comment: I am sure.  xd6_ is not correct if (s)he is saying that `ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H` is a file.  It is a `#define` for the preprocessor.  error_functions.h is the file.